# Is an object-oriented approach the right solution for my task? If so, rough idea on how to implement it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Currently attempting to develop something for my work that could be used by others. I know that the object-oriented approach is considered important so I'm trying to envision how I would use that for what I'm trying to do, but failing to see how.

I'm writing a web scraper in python using Selenium. There are tables of data that can be accessed for different clients and I would like to allow future users of my program to pull one (or maybe multiple) tables to see the data, or to use it to validate that things are properly populating on the website.

The code is still a work in progress, and I'm attempting to learn best practices and the right way to do things. Any other feedback is welcomed, I want to learn.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import getpass
import bs4
import time

###Open a headless Chrome, grab the URL page, enter into username and password, POST
chop = Options()
driver = input().strip()
if driver == "y":
     chop.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"<Path to Chromedriver.exe placeholder>", options=chop)
driver.get("<URL placeholder>")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
element.clear()
element.send_keys(input("Username: ").strip())
element = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element.clear()
element.send_keys(getpass.getpass().strip())
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

###Select a client, navigate to a table
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("<ID placeholder>"))
select.select_by_value(input("Client #:").strip())
element = driver.find_element_by_id("<ID placeholder>")
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_id("<ID placeholder>")
element.click()

###Attempt to grab the entire table, print it out in terminal
###1 second sleep semi-necessary to give page time to load table
time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

###Print out grabbed rows
for L in element[2:-2]: 
    print(L.text)

driver.quit()
```

So far it just lets you navigate to one of the tables and grabs all the rows. Some rows aren't really valid so that's why I'm slicing. The placeholders are just to hide what I'm actually working on, don't think the company would like a bunch of random people finding the website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review, which is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GregBurghardt Okay. I was asking how an object oriented approach would be applied to using a web scraper in a way, if that is considered code review then I'll close it.

Answer (score 0):

`selenium` is already implemented using an object oriented approach. OOP is designed to help reduce the stress of trying to expand projects with extra requirements, or in your case, lets say I wanted to scrape an additional website, you'd have to write a unique script for each website.  One of the ways I abstract `selenium` is by creating a [controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that manages all of the overhead for `selenium` and then is initialized with a list of *parsers* that are responsible for scraping individual websites and returning their results. This is probably better explained with code:

```py
class WebParser:
  def parse(browser: webdriver.Firefox):
    # A unique script for handling this particular webpage
    ...


class SeleniumController:
  def __init__(parsers: list[WebParser]):
    self.parsers = parsers
    self.browser = webdriver.FireFox()
    # Finish initializing browser either here, or in a separate function
    ...

  def trigger():
    result = []
    for p in self.parsers:
      result.append(p.parse(self.browser))
    # Handle your results
    ...
```

You can then create a child class of `WebParser` for each different webpage that you need to parse.

This kind of problem might also benefit form using a [adapter pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter) or some sort of [abstract factory](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory) to aid in creating web parsers at runtime.  [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru/) is an amazing site for applying object oriented concepts to different kinds of problems

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will look over the Refactoring Raccoon later.
If I were to create child classes of WebParser, then would the list of WebParsers used in the initialization of SeleniumController accept derived classes of WebParser?

Comment: Yes, because the base class is still `WebParser` so the method `parse()` will still exist, you could also just replace `parsers: list[WebParser]` with `parsers: list` it doesn't matter, I'm just showing types for guidance